# Lifespan of LocalStorage data

Tags: html, local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DOM Storage expires time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/dom-storage-expires-time)

I'm wondering how long data exists inside of LocalStorage. What I've gathered is that it is permanent until cleared by the application or the user.