# Does HTML5 localStorage have an expiry date?

Tags: html, local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DOM Storage expires time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/dom-storage-expires-time)

If I add some data to the browser's local storage, does it expire naturally? I'm thinking of storing some data with HTML 5 local storage, but the nature of it means it would expire after a few weeks.

So I'm wondering if there is a method to check if the data needs updating? Or simply update the data every few weeks.