# Persistent storage in browser

Tags: javascript, persistence, local-storage

Currently we are using localStorage as persistent storage in our application. But we noticed that it is prone to data loss. Here is some links which supports this:

[HTML5 Local Storage Not Persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072797/html5-local-storage-not-persistent)

[localStorage data persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728946/localstorage-data-persistence)

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132952-localstorage-doesn-t-save-all-data

So now I'm searching for a new solution. It will be good if this solution is supported by chrome/safari at iOS/Android. Could someone suggest something?

Comment: for persistent storage store the data on server..

Comment: This app should work in offline mode :)

Comment: It is usual website. But yes. It should be used at mobile platforms mainly.

Comment: It looks like the [chrome developers are trying to do something](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage) about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. if its a website then, there is no means of persistent storage on browser. localstorage, database, cookies, everything is erased if user don't require them. So the only option would be to store the data on the server.

   OR
2. if it is a mobile app (phonegap), then you can use [SQL Lite](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.opendatabase.md.html).

Comment: For 2 - remember though I can still use remote debugging and delete the data. Nothing on the client is safe from - well - the client.