# Spotify - Cookies not saved

Tags: spotify

Within the JS of a Spotify application, I'm saving a cookie, which can be retrieved fine within other pages of the same application.

However, after quitting and starting Spotify again, the cookie is not there anymore.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: Maybe it's a session cookie? What does the expiry time say?

Comment: Err..yeah, apparently I hadn't set the expire time.

Answer (score 1):

Use localstarage instead. Cookies are not stored on disk.

```
 localStorage.setItem("name", "Hello World!"); 



 localStorage.getItem("name"); // Hello World!
```

Comment: Does local storage have some sort of an expiry time?

Comment: Nope, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire