# make localStorage or sessionStorage expire like cookies

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do items in HTML5 local storage expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire)

My web application uses client side storage (`sessionStorage` and `localStorage`). However, I want this data to be expired after some time (eg. 2 days). It was a super easy task with *expiration date* of [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) but I don't know how to set an expiration date for HTML5 storage.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Efficiency and simplicity is important.

Comment: Store an _expiration date_ into the storage then take decisions such as cleaning data!

Comment: Some bad news for you, friend. Looks like it is up to the user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire 

I am sure you can store timestamps, compare and reject if it is too old though.

Comment: I agree with @kush. store the expiry timestamp and decide when reading.

Comment: Great news! It's up to the user. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30730835/873650

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best you can do is to set a timestamp in storage, and if the user visits your site after a specified amount of time, then you can delete the stored data.

`sessionStorage` should work the same way, except when it doesn't even last long enough for your timed expiration. In that case, it'll expire sooner.

Comment: the only caveat, they need to **visit again**. Otherwise, it can keep persisting.

Answer (score 1):

The `Storage` model was meant to be a cache for scripts; not of a spur-of-the-moment data holder. Infact `sessionStorage` **should** clear as soon as the protocol+domain is navigated away from. With that said, the simplest way would be to store and check a 'hold-until' value at each page view, and update/clear-storage it as needed