# How can I fix this local storage HTML5 error?

Tags: html, textarea, local-storage

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. When the save button is clicked it is supposed to send the text from the textarea into local storage. Then when you close and reopen the page the text that was saved is supposed to come back. But when I close the document and open it again, it is blank. Is there a mistake that I am overlooking, or should I try a different method to save to local storage?

```
<script>
function save () {
    var inputvalue = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
    localstorage.setItem('text', inputvalue);
}

function load() {
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
    if(storedValue) {
        document.getElementById('textfield').value = storedValue;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
 <textarea id="textfield">
 </textarea>
 <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save()" />
</body>
```

Comment: Did you first give save? Did you just close the tab or end the browser session? If you end the browser session, `localStorage` gets cleared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do items in HTML5 local storage expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire)