# Lifetime of window.localStorage.setItem()

Tags: javascript

I am creating an app using phonegap. I want to use local storage. I have seen some example that i cat store it using.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('variablename','value');
```

I cant find anywhere about its details. I dont know about it lifetime. If i am storing some value how much time it will stay. Means i want to know will this expire like cookies or session, after some time it will expired automatically. Or it will be stored for lifetime?

Could anyone tell me about this variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely upto the u.There is no definite lifetime of it.you can have a look at the following.It might help you.
http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-storage/