# Local Storage vs Cookies: save and send user credentials via websockets

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cookies, websocket, local-storage

***I have:*** websocket secure connection (wss) through the whole app. + Backbone.js on client side if it's significant.

***I want:*** automatically log in user on new tab opening, if he's already logged in another tab.

***Question:*** what is better either use cookies or localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use localStorage, the user's credentials will be stored (presumable unencrypted unless you implement this yourself) on the user's local machine. These records will [not expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire) unless you write your application to do this. As such your user would be logged in forever, not just if they have another tab open, unless you also wrote logic for that. But there is no reason to do all this additional work.

Cookies are already frequently used to accomplish this functionality. Inside the cookie you should store a session token, which identifies the user's session uniquely. Cookies have the advantage of automatic expiration, and are automatically passed to the server with each HTTP request. For more information about the differences between cookies and localStorage, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies?rq=1) thread.

Comment: Cookies are not passed along with Web Socket messages. They are passed along with all HTTP requests though.

Comment: Edited to specify HTTP requests.