# How can I remove local storage after one hour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

My data is object

I save it use local storage javascript like this :

```
localStorage.setItem('storedData', JSON.stringify(data))
```

I just want to keep that data for 1 hour. So if it's been more than 1 hour then the data will be removed

I know to remove data like this :

```
localStorage.removeItem("storedData")
```

But how can I set it to auto delete after 1 hour?

Comment: use setTimeout() function to clear it.

Comment: Don't know if it would work for you, but you could set a cookie that expires in one hour and store the data in there instead?

Answer (score 20):

You can't.
[When do items in HTML5 local storage expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire)
The only thing you can do is set the delete statement in a timeout of 1 hour. **This requires the user to stay on your page or the timeout won't be executed.**

You can also set an expiration field. When the user revisits your site, check the expiration and delete the storage on next visit as the first thing you do.

Comment: The "expiration field" is usually more practical, as the setTimeout approach requires the user to remain on the same *page* for an hour. Unless you are writing an SPA or are using frames, that is rarely a practical scenario.

Answer (score 14):

Add the following code in your App.js file, then the localStorage will be cleared for every 1 hour

```
var hours = 1; // to clear the localStorage after 1 hour
               // (if someone want to clear after 8hrs simply change hours=8)
var now = new Date().getTime();
var setupTime = localStorage.getItem('setupTime');
if (setupTime == null) {
    localStorage.setItem('setupTime', now)
} else {
    if(now-setupTime > hours*60*60*1000) {
        localStorage.clear()
        localStorage.setItem('setupTime', now);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't use setTimeout().Since you can't guarantee your code is going to be running on the browser in 1 hours. But you can set a timestamp and while returning back just check with Timestamp and clear the storage out based on expiry condition.

Answer (score 6):

use setInterval, with setting/pushing expiration key in your local data, 
check code below.

```
var myHour = new Date();
myHour.setHours(myDate.getHours() + 1); //one hour from now
data.push(myHour);
localStorage.setItem('storedData', JSON.stringify(data))

function checkExpiration (){ 
    //check if past expiration date
        var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedData'));
    //check "my hour" index here
    if (values[1] < new Date()) {
        localStorage.removeItem("storedData")
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    var myinterval = 15*60*1000; // 15 min interval
    setInterval(function(){ checkExpiration(); }, myinterval );
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use cookies instead

`Cookies.set('foo_bar', 1, { expires: 1/24 })`

Comment: Not answering the question. The capacity of cookies are very small.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) in [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). What it basically means is you can create a parallel to your main thread JavaScript program, like this

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

The advantage is when it finishes its work, and you don't have a reference to it, it gets cleaned up automatically.
However, since I'm not fully sure about the above, here is **The worker's lifetime** from [Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#the-worker%27s-lifetime)

> Workers communicate with other workers and with browsing contexts
> through message channels and their MessagePort objects.
>
> Each WorkerGlobalScope object worker global scope has a list of the
> worker's ports, which consists of all the MessagePort objects that are
> entangled with another port and that have one (but only one) port
> owned by worker global scope. This list includes the implicit
> MessagePort in the case of dedicated workers.
>
> Given an environment settings object o when creating or obtaining a
> worker, the relevant owner to add depends on the type of global object
> specified by o. If o specifies a global object that is a
> WorkerGlobalScope object (i.e., if we are creating a nested dedicated
> worker), then the relevant owner is that global object. Otherwise, o
> specifies a global object that is a Window object, and the relevant
> owner is the responsible document specified by o.
> A worker is said to be a permissible worker if its WorkerGlobalScope's
> owner set is not empty or:
>
> - its owner set has been empty for no more than a short implementation-defined timeout value,
> - its WorkerGlobalScope object is a SharedWorkerGlobalScope object (i.e., the worker is a shared worker), and
> - the user agent has a browsing context whose Document object is not completely loaded.

Another advantage is you can terminate a worker, like this

```
worker.terminate();
```

Also, it is worth mentioning

> IndexedDB has built-in support for schema versions and upgrading via
> its [IDBOpenDBRequest.onupgradeneeded()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBOpenDBRequest/onupgradeneeded) method; however, you still
> need to write your upgrade code in such a way that it can handle the
> user coming from a previous version (including a version with a bug).

Answer (score 0):

This works for a SPA where the browser window doesn't reload on page renders:

Set an `expiresIn` field in your local storage.
On window reload check to see `if current time >= expiresIn`
`if true clear localStorage items else carry on`
You can also do this check whenever your business logic requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the check in your app to check if the variable exists and then do a check on it. Put a [unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) on the variable, and compare that the next time the user visits your site.

Answer (score -2):

I think setTimeout() method will do the trick.

**UPDATED:**

While setting the value to localStorage also set the time of recording the data.

```
// Store the data with time
const EXPIRE_TIME = 1000*60*60;
localStorage.setItem('storedData', JSON.stringify({
  time: new Date(),
  data: "your some data"
}));

// start the time out

setTimeout(function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('storedData');
}, EXPIRE_TIME); // after an hour it will delete the data
```

Now the problem is if user leave the site. And setTimeout will not work. So when user next time visit the site you have to bootstrap the setTimeout again.

```
// On page load
$(document).ready(function() {
  let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedData')) || {};
  let diff = new Date() - new Date(userData.time || new Date());
  let timeout = Math.max(EXPIRE_TIME - diff, 0);
  setTimeout(function() {
      localStorage.removeItem('storedData');
  }, timeout);
})
```

Comment: No! setTimeout dies when you exit the page.

Comment: [delete_this.jpeg]

Comment: setTimeout().we can't make sure our code is going to be running on the browser.

Comment: Damn, this is so BAD!