# How can i set timeout for localstorage for Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, angular6, angular2-routing

I want to make a timeout for my Angular 2+ Application .
Actually,i want after some time like 20 minutes localtorage got cleared .

Thanks

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/

Comment: Thanks nice solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write setTimeout function with in ngOnInit.

```
ngOnInit(){

   setTimeout(()=>{
      localStorage.clear();
},time)

}
```

Comment: better to use sessionStorage