# How to save textarea content in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, save, textarea

When i press save content in textarea need to be saved in localstorage and next time this content in localstorage will be place in textarea when site will be again opened.

[Full code in code pen](https://codepen.io/TheLexa/pen/zgRZjb)

```js
**JS**
//save txtarea input local storage ..
function SaveBtn(){
var input_textarea = document.querySelector('#result');
var save_button = document.querySelector('#SaveBtn');

save_button.addEventListener('click', updateOutput);

input_textarea.textContent = localStorage.getItem('content');
input_textarea.value = localStorage.getItem('content');

function updateOutput() {
     Del();
 localStorage.setItem('content', input_textarea.value);
    input_textarea.textContent = input_textarea.value;
}
}
```

Don't have any error or warning when i press save. 
[image: This is how textarea and save button look like]

I want when next time visite site in this text area be 3*3=9 for this user.

Comment: You don't appear to have a `Del()` function... and you attempt to call it *before* setting the item to `localStorage`. Assuming this in (in theory) hooked up to your delete button, this would remove the content anyway.

Comment: This del() is for button fuction (Delete) button who work good.

Comment: @AleksaKovacevic There is no way to predict how long an item will persist in local storage, I invite you to read this other SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326943/when-do-items-in-html5-local-storage-expire). If you really needed to persist a value for a user until their next visit to a website or page you are developing, a database would be the place to put it.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks for help

Comment: @AleksaKovacevic Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var editor = document.querySelector("#editor");
      if (window.localStorage["TextEditorData"]) {
            editor.value = window.localStorage["TextEditorData"];
      }    
      editor.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      window.localStorage["TextEditorData"] = editor.value;
      });
```

```html
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.